# How do I upgrade a PostgreSQL Heroku database using flask migrate after not having used flask migrate on the production site?

Tags: flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am working a website using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and Flask Migrate for database upgrades. So far 99.9% of my work has been local and I haven't worried about any production implications for when I make my website live. However, recently I've uploaded my git repo to heroku and made my website live. My migrations folder from flask migrate was in my gitignore because my brother and I who are working on it felt like we should have different migration folders (however the more I think about it, the more it seems more convenient to just have one folder on git that we call upgrade on each time we pull a change). So, this meant that the production site had no migrate folder on it and all I did to get it working was to destroy the database and run db.create_all() to build it.

Now, however, I know that this is not sustainable if I want to have any sort of retainable information in the database after a schema change. So, I took migrate out of gitignore and pushed it to the main branch for production. Since the last version of the database I uploaded to the production site there has been many changes so I wanted to migrate those changes. I didn't run flask db init (since there was already a migrate folder) and instead ran flask db migrate to migrate my changes. This produced the expected output:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'user_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'user(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'twok_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'twok(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'fivek_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'fivek(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'metric_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'metric(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'metric.has_update'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'metric.for_coxswain'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'user.is_head'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'user.deleted'
  Generating /app/migrations/versions/a470127eb7c5_.py ...  done
```

However, when I tried to upgrade the changes to this database, I recieved little feedback and no actual schema update was completed:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

I repeated this maybe like 8 times with different variations of flask migrate commands with no success and (I presume) 8 of the same migration file. I'm not sure where I forgot a step but if anyone has any idea how to get the database to properly upgraded any help would be greatly appreciated. I need to have a way so that I can upgrade my production database at any point (when there is actual data inside of it) and preserve all previous data and schema. Thanks.

Comment: "My migrations folder from flask migrate was in my gitignore because my brother and I who are working on it felt like we should have different migration folders (however the more I think about it, the more it seems more convenient to just have one folder on git that we call upgrade on each time we pull a change)"—yes, this was a mistake. Your migrations should _definitely_ be tracked, shared among all developers, and used to migrate your production database.

Comment: That's very good to know. And this migration folder -- since it is posted to git and the Heroku server runs off the repo -- should it be the same for the production server as well as the test?

Comment: Your migration files are part of your application. They should be shared _everywhere_ your application runs, though you'll probably have different revisions in each place. You and your brother might both have migrations you haven't shared yet, your staging server might be running version `1.1`, and your production server might be running version `1.0`. Since the migrations are just files tracked in your repository alongside your other application files, each version should line up with the code running in each environment.